# Rotation respective to spherical coordinate frame

Tags: geometry

I  studied mechanics engineering the subject "rigid body mechanics", among others. Due my curiosity, I learned about Lagrangian mechanics, which I now can see as the geodesic curve of a metric space given by the system generalized inertia tensor, a "summed-up matrix" of all concerned bodies.

$$\sum\limits_i \left(m_i \langle v_{g, i}, v_{g, i} \rangle_{T\mathbb{R}^3} + \langle \omega_i, \omega_i \rangle_{I_i}\right)$$

Each body has the so-called Jacobian matrix $J_i$, below, which in geometric terms, represents some vectorial representation respective to state velocity space $\dot{q} \in T_q \mathcal{Q}$. You know, we see the jacobian as the pullback of some base space $f_*$

$$v_{g, i} = J_{v_{g, i}} \dot{q}$$

$$\omega_i = J_{\omega_i} \dot{q}$$

I wonder something about satellite modelling, just a sketch however. It is possible to think of position and angular pose for a satellite, position $(x, y, z)$, always respective to (moving ;-P ) Earth  must be given in  spherical coordinates $(\lambda, \theta, r)$, which makes $J_{v_g}$ correspond to partial derivative $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial [\lambda, \theta, r]^\intercal}$ such that map $\varphi(\lambda, \theta, r)$ corresponds to spherical transformation map. There are also ways to obtain the angular vector $\omega_i$ based on time derivative of body rotation $R(q)^\intercal R(q)$. In Euclidean coordinate frame, the below skew matricial version of angular velocity $\omega_{\times}$ corresponds to $R^\intercal \dot{R}$ since $\frac{d}{dt}(R^\intercal R) = \dot{R}^\intercal R + R^\intercal \dot{R} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (R^\intercal \dot{R})^\intercal = - R^\intercal \dot{R}$.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -\omega_z & \omega_y \\
\omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\
-\omega_y & \omega_x & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

This is where my question comes in: We can use some angular representation, like Euler angles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) to define a body's pose according to local coordinate frame, for example, Euclidean coordinate frame. But once we have this same representation, by definition, will not affect the vector, but only its components. Still, these angular pose is still given respective to Earth, I think in local spherical coordinate basis, the vectors of jacobian $\varphi_*$.

Am I overthinking?